# Cardinal of the domain of a net

Tags: convergence-divergence, cardinals, nets

> **Definition:** A net $\nu$ is said to be a subnet of net $\nu',$ if there exists some function $\varphi:\mathrm{dom}(\nu)\to \mathrm{dom}(\nu'),$ such that
>
> $\bf 1)$ $\nu=\nu'\circ\varphi,$
>
> $\bf 2)$ for each $n\in \mathrm{dom}(\nu'),$ there exists some $n'\in \mathrm{dom}(\nu),$ such that $d'\in \mathrm{dom}(\nu),\ d'\geqslant n'\Longrightarrow \varphi(d')\geqslant n.$

Suppose that we have a net $\nu,$ and there is a cardinal $\kappa$ satisfying $\kappa\geqslant \mathrm{Card}\big(\mathrm{dom}(\nu)\big)\geqslant \aleph_0.$

**Question:**  Can we always find a net $\nu'$ such that $\mathrm{Card}\big(\mathrm{dom}(\nu')\big)=\kappa,$ and $\nu$ is a subnet of $\nu'?$

**P.S.** I encounter this problem when trying to find out the relationship between nets and sequences. If the answer is affirmative, then I could prove a very powerful theorem about the cardinal of nets.:)

Comment: What do you mean by a *net* and its domain here?

Comment: A net is a mapping $\nu:I\to E,$ here $I$ is a directed set, and $I$ is a directed set. And $\mathrm{dom}(\nu)=I$ is the domain of $\nu.$

Comment: Isn't there any criterium on this mapping? If no, just extend it by a constant value of $E$..

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the def'n (part 2): $b$ should be $n$.

Comment: You're right, I've corrected it now.

Comment: It is clear that in fact there is no **set** no of nets into $X$, just a **class**. We can use a lot of index sets... This is why filters are often easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can always do this pretty trivially; roughly speaking, you just add irrelevant junk to the start of the net.  Let $I=\mathrm{dom}(\nu)$ (with order $\leq_I$) and let $J$ be a set of cardinality $\kappa$ which contains $I$ as a subset.  Pick any partial order $\leq_{J\setminus I}$ on the set $J\setminus I$ and let $${\leq_J}={\leq_{J\setminus I}}\cup{\leq_I}\cup (J\setminus I)\times I.$$  That is, we order $J$ by using $\leq_I$ on $I$, $\leq_{J\setminus I}$ on $J\setminus I$, and saying that every element of $J\setminus I$ is less than every element of $I$.  It is easy to check that $\leq_J$ is a directed partial order.

Now let $\nu'$ be any extension of $\nu$ to a function defined on all of $J$ (just define it arbitrarily on $J\setminus I$).  Then $\nu$ is a subnet of $\nu'$, via the inclusion map $I\to J$ (since every element of $I$ is greater than every element of $J\setminus I$).

Comment: Excellent! Now everything is clear.